# Using loops with arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, char

```
#include <stdio.h>    

void main()
{
    char couples[3][50] = { "Paul Kathy", "John Nora", "Martin Mary" };
    char husbands[3][50];
    char wives[3][50];  
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    puts("Husbands: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        while (couples[i][j] != ' ')
        {
            couples[i][j] = husbands[i][j];
            j++;
        }
        husbands[i][j] = '\0';
        puts(husbands[i]);
        j = 0;
    }

}
```

I have created a program similar to this before and it ran perfectly. However while this does build and compile successfully, it doesn't run correctly. Essentially, I'm trying to separate couples into a separate string based up the space character. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `main` has two valid signatures: `int main (void)` and `int main (int, char **)`. Any literature teaching you otherwise should be avoided. Seek better learning material and it won't be so hard to get a grasp on the basics of C.

Comment: "it doesn't run correctly"? What does it do?

Comment: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for the full details of what is and is not allowed.  The number of platforms where `void main()` is allowed is rather small.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
couples[i][j] = husbands[i][j];
```

You are assigning `husbands` to `couples` and not the other way around as you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Try something simple.  The `sscanf()` function can extract data from strings rather easily:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char couples[3][50] = { "Paul Kathy", "John Nora","Martin Mary" };
    char husbands[3][50];
    char wives[3][50];  
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        /* Extract husband and wife names. You know they are separated by a space. */
        sscanf(couples[i], "%s %s", husbands[i], wives[i]);
    }
}
```

The issues in the original code include:

1. Couple string was getting over-written by husband string which was not initialized.
2. Not extracting wife names.

Comment: You should explain what you're doing (and drop the boilerplate comment that shouldn't be in the original question either).  You should also explain what's wrong with the original code — why wasn't it workinig.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the feedback. I have updated my answer. Please review it.